# How can two buttons do two different actionevents?

Tags: java, event-handling

What is the best way to define the action a button will perform in the code? I want to be able to have one button do one action and the next button do a different action. Is this possible?

Comment: by google, to be specific

Comment: Have you looked at the javadoc at all? There are some very clearly related methods there.

Comment: you mean Swing, to have it listen to events like clicks?
add an actionListener:

myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    System.out.println("click");
  }
});

Comment: Yes i have looked at the java docs and Thank you Stultuske

Comment: ok i now realize how stupid the question i first asked sounded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add action listener like this.

```
jBtnSelection.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    selectionButtonPressed();
  } 
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way.

```
 JButton button = new JButton("Button Click");
 button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
 {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
      //do your implementation
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

`JButton` subclasses `AbstractButton`, which has a method, [`addActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener-java.awt.event.ActionListener-). By calling this method and passing it the action listener you wish to add, the action listener is added and will be called once an action is fired, either programatically, or by way of user interaction. Other listners can be added such as [mouse listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have your class implement ActionListener. Then implement the actionPerformed() method. Here is an example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Driver extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3549094714969732803L;

    private JButton button = new JButton("Click");

    public Driver(){
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,4));
        p.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        add(p);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Driver frame = new Driver();
        frame.setSize(500,200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
    }
}
```